# Is possible to define the topology of compact convergence on a product of metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Many texts define the uniform topology on a functions space but it is actually possible (is it true?) to define on an arbitrary product: in fact, let be $\frak X$ a collection of sets so that if $\overline d_X$ is the standard bounded metric for any $X\in\frak X$ corresponding to a metric $d_X$ on $X$ then the position
$$
d_\infty(x_1,x_2):=\sup_{X\in\frak X}\overline d_X\big(x_1(X),x_2(X)\big)
$$
for any $x_1,x_2\in\prod\frak X$ defines a metric for $\prod\frak X$ which is just the (calssical) topology of uniform convergence when $Y_x$ is for any $x$ just a metric space $Y$. Analogously many texts define the topology of compact convergence on a functions space so that by the above case I asked to me if it possible to generalize the compact topology on a product indexed on a topological space which coincides with the usual one when any factor is equal to only one metric space: in fact, let be $Y$ the product of a collection
$$
\mathfrak Y:=\big\{(Y_x,d_x):x\in X\big\}
$$
of metric spaces indexed on a set $X$ so that if $\mathcal T_X$ is a topology on $X$ then for any $K\in\mathcal P(X)$ compact with respect $\mathcal T_X$, for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ and for any $v\in Y$ we can put
$$
B_K(v,\epsilon):=\big\{u\in Y:\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),u(x)\big)\big\}
$$
and so if $\cal K$ is the set of all compact subspace of $X$ with respect $\mathcal T_X$ then putting
$$
\mathcal B_y:=\big\{B_K(y,\epsilon):(K,\epsilon)\in\cal K\times\Bbb R^+\big\}
$$
for any $y\in Y$ let's we prove that
$$
\mathcal B:=\bigcup_{y\in Y} \mathcal B_y
$$
is a base for any topology $\mathcal T_K$ on $Y$. So, fixex $v\in Y$, we immediately observe that if $w\in B_K(v,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ and with $K\in\cal K$ then putting
$$
\varepsilon:=\epsilon-\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),w(x)\big)
$$
the inclusion
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}B_K(w,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_K(v,\epsilon)
$$
since if $u\in B_K(w,\varepsilon)$ then for any $\xi\in K$ the inequality
$$
\overline d_\xi\big(v(\xi),u(\xi)\big)\le \overline d_\xi\big(v(\xi),w(\xi)\big)+\overline d_\xi\big(w(\xi),u(\xi)\big)
$$
holds but even the inequalities
$$
\tag{a}\overline d_\xi\big(v(\xi),u(\xi)\big)\le\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),w(x)\big)
$$
$$
\tag{b}\overline d_\xi\big(w(\xi),u(\xi)\big)\le\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(w(x),u(x)\big)
$$
holds so that actually the inequality
$$
\overline d_\xi\big(v(\xi),u(\xi)\big)\le\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),w(x)\big)+\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(w(x),u(x)\big)
$$
holds which proves that
$$
\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),u(x)\big)\le\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(v(x),w(x)\big)+\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(w(x),u(x)\big)
$$
So, if $y_1,y_2\in Y$ and if $K_2,K_2\in\cal K$ then for any $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in\Bbb R^+$ let's we suppose that $y\in Y$ is such that
$$
y\in B_{K_i}(y_i,\epsilon_i)
$$
for $i=1,2$ so that by \eqref{1} the inclusion
$$
B_{K_i}(y,\varepsilon_i)\subseteq B_{K_i}(y_i,\epsilon_i)
$$
holds, where
$$
\varepsilon_i:=\epsilon_i-\sup_{x\in K_i}\overline d_x\big(y(x),y_i(x)\big)
$$
Now we remember that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are two subset of $\Bbb R$ such that the first is contained into the second then the supremum of the first is less than the supremum of the second, provided this exists: so, putting
$$
K:=K_1\cup K_2
$$
we observe that if $y_0\in B_K(y,\varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon\le\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ then for $i=1,2$ the inequality
$$
\sup_{x\in K_i}\overline d_x\big(y(x),y_0(x)\big)\le\sup_{x\in K}\overline d_x\big(y(x),y_0(x)\big)<\varepsilon\le\varepsilon_i
$$
holds so that $y_0\in B_{K_i}(y,\varepsilon_i)$ and thus finally the inclusion
$$
\tag{2}B(y,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_{K_1}(y_1,\varepsilon_1)\cap B_{K_2}(y_2,\epsilon_2)
$$
holds. Moreover, the singleton set are compact so that fixed $x\in X$ and $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ any $y\in Y$ is such that
$$
\tag{1}y\in B_x(y,\epsilon)
$$
which proves that $\cal B$ cover $Y$. So we conclude that $\cal B$ is actually a base for a topology on $Y$ which is obviously a generalization of topology of compact convergence since if $Y_x$ is just a metric space $M$ for any $x\in X$ then $\mathcal T_K$ is exactly the (usual) topology of compact convergence.

So I ask if what I done is right since I did not find it anywhere but I elaborate it by myself: so is possible to define the topology of compact convergence on a product of metric spaces? what I done above shows that is this possible?

Comment: The compact -open topology

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. You want to apply the uniform convergence topology to arbitrary product spaces? What does “uniform convergence” mean if we aren’t talking about function spaces?

Comment: @FShrike I ask if it possible to generalize the topology of compact convergence on a product of metric spaces, that's all.

Comment: @FShrike Anyway  I try to explain well: many texts define the topology of uniform convergence on $Y^X$ where $X$ is a set and $Y$ is a metric space but if $Y_x$ is for any $x\in X$ a metric space then it is actually possibile to define a topology on $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x$ which is just the topology of uniform convergence when $Y_x$ is just a metric space $Y$ for any $x\in X$ so that I ask if it is possibile to do an analogous think for the topology of the compact convergence. Is now clear what I am asking?

Comment: You can view the set: $$\prod_{x\in X}Y$$As the set of functions $X\to Y$. As this includes discontinuous ones, I suspect there is no topology of convergence here

Comment: @FShrike Well, I really think that the topology of uniform convergence is notable topology for $Y^X$.

Comment: @FShrike E.g. one interesting thing could be that when $X$ is finite then the uniform topology coincides just with the product topology whereas if $X$ is not finite then the product topology is just contained into the uniform topology: so we know that any product of metric spaces has a metric which is just compatible with the product topology when the product is finite and which is finer then the product topology otherwise; moreover, the uniform topology is always less finer then box topology.

Comment: Passing to $\bar d_x=\min\{d_x,1\}$ (as you did anyway) you may assume $d_x\le 1$. This helps to find a single metric space $(Y,d)$ which contains all $Y_x$ as closed subsets and $d$ restricts to $d_x$ on $Y_x$, namely, the disjoint (or rather *disjointified*) union $Y=\bigsqcup_{x\in X} Y_x$ with $d(y,z)=d_x(y,z)$ if $y,z$ belong to the same $Y_x$ and $d(y,z)=1$ otherwise. The you can consider the compact-open topology in $Y^X$ and restric it to $\prod_{x\in X} Y_x$.

Comment: @Jochen It is clear how equipped $Y$ with a metric but $\prod_{x\in X}Y^X$ is not contained in $Y$, right? So, perhaps do you implicitly embed it into $Y$? could you explain better, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Perhaps I understood then a basic open set for the compact-open topology in $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x$ would be a set $$S(K,U):=\{f\in\prod_{x\in X}Y_x:f[K]\subseteq U\}$$  where $K$ is compact in $X$ and $U$ open in $Y$ with respect $d$, right?

Comment: Yes, $Y_x$ are cosidered as subsets of $Y$ and $\prod_{x\in X} Y_x$ is identified with $\{f\in Y^X: f(x)\in Y_x$ for every $x\in X\}$.

Comment: @Jochen Okay, so I argue that what I did is possible: that is, it is possibile define the topology of compact convergence on $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x$ when $Y_x$ is **not** just a only metric space for any $x\in X$ and additionally it is possibile to define open-compact topology which is finer then pointwise and which is equal to the usual one when $Y_x$ is just a only metric space for any $x\in X$, right?